# Term for the category which contains Santa Claus, the Easter Bunny, etc?

Tags: phrases, generic-term

Is there a specific word or term for the group of mythical holiday characters such as Santa Claus, the Easter bunny, Cupid, etc?

Comment: This question is hard to answer without knowing which characters the poster would include or exclude. For example, the Great Pumpkin is associated with Halloween (in the United States) but isn't a product of folk tradition. Father Time and Baby New Year are associated with New Year's Eve and Day, but they don't possess any notable supernatural powers (other than reappearing each year unchanged except for the date on their sashes). The Tooth Fairy has supernatural powers but is not tied to a particular holiday (unless you happen to celebrate October 21 as National Dental Health Day).

Answer (score 2):

I might call such characters [***holiday mascots***](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=%22holiday+mascots). Just as a [mascot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mascot) might represent a brand or sports team, these characters represent their respective cultural holidays.

Comment: Not bad. So Pratchett's _Hogfather_ character would be included. But not his _Death_ character, even though they are both "anthropomorphic personifications", as Pratchett calls them. I.e, they are persons brought into existence by belief of humanity in a strong magical field, such as the one on Discworld. Humans on our world, of course, have no such excuse.

Comment: This in my view is a classic example of the way that commerce has dumbed-down our cultural heritage. A term like 'holiday mascots' perhaps adequately explains, for the purposes of advertising, sales of chocolate eggs etc. what they regrettably have become in today's world. But it is a term which force-fits things together, which do not belong together, and further obscures the saga of each the figures and their individual places in history. Seldom do I cast a negative vote, but on this occasion I feel moved to do so, for the sake of jolly old St Nicholas!

Comment: Will you include the Chinese 'Hungry Ghosts'?

Comment: Agree with @WS2 re: the connotations of 'Mascot'.  How about 'Holiday Heroes'?

Comment: @RSG What exactly is heroic about the Easter Bunny? Why in heaven's name do they have to be 'holiday' anythings? The notion of 'holiday' in the sense in which we are using it here, is in any case a very recent idea. 'Festival' is vastly more appropriate, and includes all the non-Christian festivals celebrated in English-speaking countries (which are not public holidays) from the Druid solstice to Hindu Diwali. If you must collectivise these disparate figures, call them 'festival icons'. But even that is outrageously insensitive to cultural history, in my view.

Comment: @WS2- with respect to the hijacked druidic traditions, etc. sure, it's a shame what commercialization does. I'm just looking for language to categorize a group of clip art- so sadly effective communication to the average American user is the goal, not 100% historical accuracy :)

Answer (score 1):

***[festive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/festive)***

related to (religious) holidays, the *festive season* includes several holidays,eg. Christmas and Epiphany

Of course this does have religious overtones that some may not appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

*Fairytale characters* come to mind

Comment: I'm looking for something less broad- Fairytale characters includes the Big Bad Wolf et al.

Comment: --What?!! Santa Claus isn't real??!